# xypic: custom arrow shaft(stem)

Tags: arrows, xy-pic

I've noted that `xy-pic` have predefined some dir's. The tail and head (tip) are easy to custom (one can learn by `xyrefer.pdf`), but I find it hard to implement my own shaft types.

Because the dash stem is drawn evenly with a invisible space. I want to control the space step.

Tried `\newdir{}{}`, `\composite{}` but in vain. Furthermore, the following code gives ugly downward arrow:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
{
    \def\arr{ \ar@{*{\bullet}*{\cdot}*@{>}} }
    \xymatrix{ A \arr[dr]\arr[d]\arr[r] &B \\ C&D }
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`xyrefer.pdf` is so fuzzy for beginners. Even the `yacc` style Syntax-List figures are just for compilers, not for human-reading (I would prefer the Unix-command-syntax-style).

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[all,pdf,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{ A \ar @{{*}.>} [dr] \ar @{{*}.>} [d]\ar @{{*}.>} [r] & B \\ 
    C & D 
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]